# python 3 use of for loop for purpose of copying list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am doing serial communication. I have two lists, first is a single dimension list `dataList` and the other is 2D list `multiList`. from serial communication i am sending `'101','102','103',....'109'`. The sent data is stored in `dataList` and that `dataList` is stored in `multiList` row by row like the first `dataList`
should be stored in the first row of `multiList`, the second `dataList` should be stored in the second row of `multiList` and moreover. Currently, the `multilist` output is like this:

```py
[['1', '108', '109', '100', '101'], [], [], [], []]

[['102', '103', '104', '105', '106'], ['102', '103', '104', '105', '106'], [], [], []]

[['107', '108', '109', '100', '101'], ['107', '108', '109', '100', '101'], ['107', '108', '109', '100', '101'], [], []].
```

But I want my output like:

```py
[['101', '102', '103', '104', '105'], [], [], [], []]

[['101', '102', '103', '104', '105'], ['106', '107', '108', '109', '101'], [], [], []]

[['101', '102', '103', '104', '105'], ['106', '107', '108', '109', '101'], ['102', '103', '104', '105', '106'], [], []]
```

```py
import serial

row=5
col=3
multiList = ([[], [], [], [], []])

ser = serial.Serial(COM4, baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
numPoints = 5
dataList = [0] * numPoints

def getValues():
    ser.write(b'g')
    fpgadata = ser.readline().decode('ascii').split('\n')
    return fpgadata[0]

def update():
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(0, numPoints):
            dataList[i] = getValues()
    #print(dataList)
        multiList[j] = dataList
        print(multiList)

update()
```

Comment: where do the values come from? how are we expected to help you with those?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the `multiList[j] = dataList` step you don't copy the elements, only the `dataList` copy. So in fact `multiList` contains multiple references to the same list. To copy the elements into a new list, write `multiList[j] = dataList[:]`, like this:

```
def update():
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(0, numPoints):
            dataList[i] = getValues()
        multiList[j] = dataList[:]
        print(multiList)
```

This will have the desired effect of assigning to `multiList[j]` a new list,
with the elements of `dataList` copied.